# How to use Imagick to Crop Image Top , Bottom , Center

Tags: imagick

cropThumbnailImage($maxWidth,$maxHeight);

I created a php code to crop image on the fly using Imagick with class cropThumbnailImage($maxWidth,$maxHeight);  . But this class crops image at center . Is there any other way to crop image the required position like top , bottom .